# Card View material design in Windows Universal Apps

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I want to develop a Blog application similar design like [Universal MSN News App](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9wzdncrfhvfw) of Microsoft. I want similar design like shown in picture below.

I looked into this News app and found that lots of cool features is integreted with Pivot design.

Few Questions I have:

- How do I make dynamic card view layout like this in News app. This app has
  dynamic Grid View. Some GridView are bigger some are small. How do we adjust these grid view next to each other
  even if they have different heights. Are there any samples for this?
- Lazy Loading is implemented to load the feeds when we scroll down.
  Any idea how to get work done for lazy loading.

[image]

Thank you. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use some third-party library: [The-UWP-Tools-List](https://github.com/10UWP/The-UWP-Tools-List)

It's easy to integrate [Marduk.Controls](https://github.com/ProjectMarduk/Marduk.Controls) by the following command:

`PM> Install-Package Marduk.Controls`

You could see my code sample:

```cs
<Page
x:Class="App1.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:App1"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:controls="using:Marduk.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <controls:WaterfallFlowView x:Name="Panel" ItemSource="{Binding cc}" StackCount="3" DelayMeasure="True">
            <controls:WaterfallFlowView.Resizer>
                <local:MyItemResizer/>
            </controls:WaterfallFlowView.Resizer>
            <controls:WaterfallFlowView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"></Setter>
                </Style>
            </controls:WaterfallFlowView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <controls:WaterfallFlowView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Height="{Binding Length}" Background="{Binding Brush}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="{Binding Num}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:WaterfallFlowView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:WaterfallFlowView>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public ObservableCollection<Test> cc { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        cc = new ObservableCollection<Test>();
        cc.Add(new Test() {Length=200,Brush= new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red),Num=1 });
        cc.Add(new Test() { Length = 150, Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue), Num = 2 });
        cc.Add(new Test() { Length = 100, Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightCyan), Num = 3 });
        cc.Add(new Test() { Length = 50, Brush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.SandyBrown), Num = 4 });
        this.DataContext = this;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public double Length { get; set; }

    public SolidColorBrush Brush { get; set; }

    public int Num { get; set; }
}

public class MyItemResizer : IItemResizer
{
    public Size Resize(object item, Size oldSize, Size availableSize)
    {
        return new Size(availableSize.Width, oldSize.Height);
    }
}
```

[image]

[UWPCommunityToolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit)

Comment: I looked into this https://github.com/ProjectMarduk/Marduk.Controls But couldn't integrate into my app. Looking into this project it is in C++.

Comment: I installed reference using the command line. But when I add the controls:WaterfallFlowView it gives error. I don't know what I'm missing. It is not clearly mentioned in documentation. https://github.com/ProjectMarduk/Marduk.Controls

Comment: @KishorBikramOli I integrated Marduk.Controls successfully. Please check my above reply. I've update my code sample in it.

Comment: Thank You so much. I will surely try to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

## Custom-sized grids

- Create your own widget (extend the base widget class) to represent a single grid. The size of the grid will be decided by the amount of text in it or any other factor you wish.
- Use a table or grid layout. For Gtk+, see here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkGrid.html
- Attach your custom widgets to the layout.

## Lazy loading

- The scrolling widget of all toolkits I know emit a signal when the user reaches the bottom (or top or left edge or right edge).
- Catch that signal and add more custom grid widgets to the layout. You might need to redisplay the contents of the layout which is a bit inefficient; use multithreading perhaps.
- In Gtk+ 3, edge-reached is emitted by ScrolledWindow when any of the edge is reached.

*This is the general concept. A quick Google search will reveal how your choice of GUI toolkit does the above.*